# How to "open with" in a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a windows powershell script that will be available on a server to my users. I don't want them to have to go out and find the PS script, right click and click "run with powershell" or do an "open with". The Windows (Win 7 at least) default program is notepad.

I want to make a batch file to do this. I've tried:

```
start "c:\myfile.ps1" powershell.exe
```

and a few other variations, but all I've been able to do is either start powershell, or open my file in its default program, notepad.

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Bonus question: If I run my batch file as administrator will it also run my PS script as administrator?

Comment: `start "c:\myfile.ps1" powershell.exe` -> `start "" powershell.exe "c:\myfile.ps1"`

Comment: Are you saying to try: start "" powershell.exe "c:\myfile.ps1" ? Because I have tried (and just tried again) that, and it opens my ps1 file in notepad.

Comment: Yes, he is. Right now you are using the file path as the title of what you're starting. Check the syntax [here](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: Not sure where you got that syntax from. Every scripting language on the planet you put the script after the program that executes the script. Also reading the help for the start command would show you that what you essentially did was set the window title for the console.

Comment: @coinbird I seriously doubt that. Please provide evidence.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Just tested again. It was a typo on my part. My apologies, and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use the `-file` argument for PowerShell.exe in your batch file:

```
PowerShell.exe -file c:\MyFile.ps1
```

Additionally, some users may have their Execution Policy set to something that would restrict scripts from being executed, so you may want to do something like:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file c:\MyFile.ps1
```

If you would like to use `start` to launch it you can do so as Ansgar Wiechers noted by running:

```
start "" PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file c:\MyFile.ps1
```

Some notes regarding using `start`: By default it will launch PowerShell in a separate window, and continue to execute the rest of the batch file without waiting for the PowerShell window to close. If that is undesirable you have two options. You can specify `/wait` which will wait for the PowerShell window to close before continuing the batch file, or you can use the /B option will will not open a new window, and will execute PowerShell in the current console window.

And finally, yes if your batch file is run under the Administrator context, PowerShell will be as well.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `start` launches the program in a new window, while invoking `powershell.exe` directly would run the interpreter in the current (console) window.

Comment: Perfect. And I was only using start because I thought it was part of the syntax of launching a program (like powershell). Thanks so much for your help!